# Running fsck.ext3 removes symlink to device

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, udev, fsck

I have an external usb drive for which I have `udev` create the symlink `/dev/externalbackup` when it is plugged in via the following rule:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0c0b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b159", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="externalbackup"
```

This works reliably, as can be seen from

```
$ ls -l /dev/externalbackup 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan  8 09:33 /dev/externalbackup -> sdf1
```

The first partition on the device contains an `ext3` partition. If I run `fsck.ext3` on it, the symbolic link disappears:

```
$ fsck.ext3 -V
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Using EXT2FS Library version 1.42.12, 29-Aug-2014
$ fsck.ext3 -a /dev/externalbackup
/dev/externalbackup: clean, 442376/122093568 files, 146053438/488370176 blocks
$ ls -l /dev/externalbackup
ls: cannot access /dev/externalbackup: No such file or directory
```

Is this expected? Why is the symlink removed by `fsck`? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: fsck will dismount the filesystem, thus invalidating the /dev reference, one supposes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. The file system must not be (and in my example was not) mounted to run `fsck`. Also, what does the file system have to do with the block device and its symlink(s) under `/dev/`?

Comment: @kreemoweet: Dismounting the FS does nothing at all to /dev references. Remember that a /dev node must exist in order to mount it in the first place…

Comment: Can you reproduce the described behavior?